# How update update UIViewController with call supportedInterfaceOrientations and update rotation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a problem. I show `UIViewContoller` like modal and `UIViewContoller` have UIWebView. This UIWebView should show two different html page. One page have size 1024*768 and another have 768*1024. And I need show first page and then second. But I can't do it.

Example

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.isPortrait) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
}
```

First need a portrait and then landscape. But I don't know how to make `UIViewController` will turn over when load another html page.

The user can turn the iPad and then called `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and the second page starts to display correctly. But I'm not satisfied, I may be forced to reload the whole `UiViewController` that he call `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method.

Thank you